# Upvote notice went away after some seconds

Tags: support, voting

This happened already twice to me: I upvoted an answer, a blue popup appeared and before I could even start reading, it disappeared again. Now what's in that message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may have been this notice:

```
You haven't voted on questions in a while;
questions need votes too!
```

[image: The notice.]

I receive that notice whenever I vote up answers on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Yes, that was it. Maybe it's posible to show it a bit longer? I rarely upvote questions, tho.